# Is there a term used to refer to the total number of positive predictions?

Tags: classification, terminology, metric

I'm not sure how else to put it, but I often use the [`sklearn.metrics.classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) function in order to measure the performance of various classification models I'm using. Here, the term "support" is used to refer to the true number of samples for each label. In other words, it's the sum of true positives and false negatives.

I also often use the number of predicted samples as well, though, in order to get a better picture. This is the sum of true positives and false positives.

Is there any term like "support" that is used to refer to this sum? Other than "number of positive calls" as is shown in the Wikipedia page for [positive and negative predictive values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values), I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Why call it anything else when “number of positive calls” is clear enough? No need to add one more definition the reader needs to remember

Comment: So that's a "no," right? I'm trying to modify the classification report function to output the number of positive predictions as well, and was just wondering what to name the column.